# Insert a row between two existing rows in a dynamically created column in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, insert, row

I am creating a table dynamically.

Now I add some data to the table from Database.

On Every Row of the table I create a button.

Up to this it works fine.

Now when user clicks on that button I want to add a new row to the table just below the button was clicked. I mean I want to insert a new row between the existing rows.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tbl.rows.addAt(Position)
```

Here Positoion is the variable holding the value where to insert the new row.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a grid view or data table then apply the `commandname` property to the button then handle it in the grid view/data table command click method. From there you can determine which row the button is in and then create a new row and insert it below.

If you are creating the table HTML dynamically then it is a bit trickier, I would add HTML comments after each row with the row number and give each button a command argument with the row number too so I could replace the comment text with a new row.

Answer (score 0):

when use this code you can insert row between other rows in datatable in vb.net

```
    tbl.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, CurrentRow)
```